# How do stunned and delay interact?

Tags: conditions, pathfinder-2e, initiative

Character A takes the [delay](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=77) free action at the start of their turn, planning to act later. Afterwards, before Character A has acted, Big Bad Monster B inflicts [stunned](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=36) 3 upon Character A. Can Character A take the rest of their actions normally, as per delay? Would they still get 3 actions? Would they have to delay until their initiative spot, thus losing all the actions from the delay AND three actions on top of that?

What if it was [slowed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=35) 3? Does that change anything? (This might be a different question, but stunned and slowed seemed similar enough that I kept them together).

I am aware of [If a PC becomes stunned on their turn, do they lose the rest of their actions without losing any stunned value?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176770/if-a-pc-becomes-stunned-on-their-turn-do-they-lose-the-rest-of-their-actions-wi), but that deals with stunned happening **on** Character A's turn, not while they are delaying. Delaying and regaining of actions both happen at the start of the characters turn; it's unclear when a delaying character regains their actions. If a characters actions regain at the start of their previous initiative, then this question would have a different answer.

Comment: I'm going to disagree on that Close vote on the grounds that it is not readily apparent that Delay is the same as currently acting. IE Someone looking for rules about Delaying while stunned would not look up 'stunned on my turn'. Although the answer is probably the same (from my quick reading of Delay), that would not be the case in other game systems

Comment: @revenantbacon No, for the reasons Ifusaso pointed out, and as I attempted to point out in my question. I'll edit my question to attempt to make the distinction I see more clear.

Comment: Ah, so the answer being different hinges on whether you regain actions at the same time you choose to delay, or if you get them back at the point where you would act again after delaying. Gotcha. Do we have a question about that in particular? It might be a good idea to toss that up as a question as well (separately).

Comment: @RevenantBacon I am not aware of such a question; I think the answer to that question might be the same as this one, after seeing this answer, so that might get closed as a dupe of this one. However, it might be beneficial to someone searching for it... but I'm not familiar enough with SE to know if I should ask a question that I know will get closed as a dupe just to increase the scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You would lose the actions when you return from Delay**

[Starting Your Turn says](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=436)

> You can use 1 free action or reaction with a trigger of “Your turn begins” or something similar.

And later, says

> The last step of starting your turn is always the same.
> Regain your 3 actions and 1 reaction.

[Delay](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=77) triggers upon your turn starting and says

> The rest of your turn doesn’t happen yet.

Combined with the start of turn rules, if you Delay, you never reach the last step of your turn starting, and would not regain actions.

Delay also says

> You can return to the initiative order as a free action triggered by the end of any other creature’s turn.

Although it's not very explicit, this seems to imply that unDelaying (or returning to the initiative order) means you just start your turn normally again, albeit at the new initiative count, which would cause you to regain actions.

[Stunned](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=36) says, in part

> **Each time you regain actions (such as at the start of your turn)**, reduce the number you regain by your stunned value, then reduce your stunned value by the number of actions you lost.

So, when a character unDelays, they start their turn, and then regain actions. This would cause the Stun effect to now apply. If the Delayed character never unDelays, their original turn will eventually come up again, and they would then lose the actions.

[Slowed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=35) should work the same way in this case, since it also affects actions as they are regained.

Comment: Solid deduction. I was all ready to answer this wrong.

Comment: Actually, I think it might be worse than this. Since stunned precludes an actor from taking actions, the free action required to return to the initiative order could not be taken, so the delaying actor would essentially be forced to give up their turn that round, only starting their turn again when it comes back around on the following round (and does not require a free action to take).